# Capture VHS to Mac

Tags: macos, usb, digitization, vhs

I have a Mac Pro running Leopard and a RCA to USB cable and a VCR. I'm trying to figure out the best way to capture VHS tapes onto my computer using what I have. I cannot seem to find video capturing software for Macs that would do this through USB, especially for cheap or free, or with the ability to capture in MPEG2 format.

Does anyone have directions/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

USBVision or VideoGlide from [EchoFX](http://www.echofx.com/). Check to see if your RCA to USB cable is supported by either one of those. Not sure what format it imports but they claim "*high contrast, high quality video -better than DV at the same size*." You can also export to MPEG-4 or H.264.

Answer (score 0):

[elgato's video capture card](http://www.elgato.com/elgato/na/mainmenu/products/Video-Capture/product1.en.html) is $100, but it is also very good.

"Transfer video to your Mac from a VCR, DVR, camcorder, or any other analog video device as an iTunes-ready H.264 or MPEG-4 file. Elgato Video Capture’s easy-to-use software assists you through every step, from connecting an analog video source to recording the video on your Mac and choosing how you will watch and share it."